# R - Join two dataframes based on date difference

Tags: r, dataframe, join

Let's consider two dataframes df1 and df2. I would like to join dataframes based on the date difference only. For Example;

Dataframe 1: (df1)

```
| version_id | date_invoiced | product_id |
-------------------------------------------
|     1      | 03-07-2020    |   201      |
|     1      | 02-07-2020    |   2013     |
|     3      | 02-07-2020    |   2011     |
|     6      | 01-07-2020    |   2018     |
|     7      | 01-07-2020    |   201      |
```

Dataframe 2: (df2)

```
|  validfrom   | pricelist| pricelist_id |
------------------------------------------
|02-07-2020    |   10     |      101     |
|01-07-2020    |   20     |      102     |
|29-06-2020    |   30     |      103     |
|28-07-2020    |   10     |      104     |
|25-07-2020    |   5      |      105     |
```

I need to map the pricelist_id and the pricelist based on the the validfrom column present in df2. Say that, based on the least difference between the date_invoiced (df1) and validfrom (df2), the row should be mapped.

Expected Outcome:

```
| version_id | date_invoiced | product_id | date_diff | pricelist_id | pricelist |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1      | 03-07-2020    |   201      |     1     |     101      |     10    |
|     1      | 02-07-2020    |   2013     |     1     |     102      |     20    |
|     3      | 02-07-2020    |   2011     |     1     |     102      |     20    |
|     6      | 01-07-2020    |   2018     |     1     |     103      |     30    |
|     7      | 01-07-2020    |   201      |     1     |     103      |     30    |
```

I need to map purely based on the difference and the difference should be the least. Always, the date_invoiced (df1), should have closest difference comparing to validfrom (df2). Thanks

Comment: Maybe the package `fuzzyjoin` could help you in this case. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58718287/fuzzyjoin-with-dates-in-r

Comment: Shared reproducible examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you might want to try using `date.table` and nearest roll. Here, the join is made on `DATE` which would be `DATEINVOICED` from `df1` and `VALIDFROM` in `df2`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df1$DATEINVOICED <- as.Date(df1$DATEINVOICED, format = "%d-%m-%y")
df2$VALIDFROM <- as.Date(df2$VALIDFROM, format = "%d-%m-%y")

setkey(df1, DATEINVOICED)[, DATE := DATEINVOICED]
setkey(df2, VALIDFROM)[, DATE := VALIDFROM]

df2[df1, on = "DATE", roll='nearest']
```

Comment: Although the solution is close enough, I have two conditions to match; 1) df2 row count will be lesser than df1. 2) VALIDFROM should always be lesser than DATEINVOICED, that is if the DATEINVOICED is 06-07-20, then the VALIDFROM should be the closest match 05-07-20.

Comment: I see...sounds like you want to make sure the `VALIDFORM` is less than - and *not* equal to - `DATEINVOICED`...you can also try `df2[df1, on = .(DATE < DATE), mult = "last"]` assuming the dates are in order...

Comment: Or potentially you could use `roll = Inf` instead of `nearest` in the answer, but then would need to set the `DATE` in `df2` to one day earlier (`DATE - 1`) so it strictly makes sure `VALIDFROM` is less than `DATEINVOICED` and *not* equal to it...hope this is helpful...